# What are the drawback of not using "brewer's yeast" when brewing beer?

Tags: brewing, yeast

When walking through a brewery supply store, you will see a variety of yeasts.

Likewise, you can find a variety of yeasts when walking through a grocery store.

What "happens" if you use the 'wrong kind' of yeast when brewing? How much of a beer's flavor / texture / body / etc is derived from the yeast vs all other ingredients?

Comment: I think this should be on homebrew.SE - there are many similar questions there about using wine yeast or bakers' yeast to brew beer. If you want to know specifically how much of a beer's flavor/aroma profile comes from the yeast, then rephrasing the question to that affect will remove the emphasis on homebrewing.

Comment: As phrased, it's more about homebrewing.

Comment: @mdma - did not know the homebrew.SE was live: and actually cannot see why it shouldn't be part of this site, as "homebrew" is exclusively about "beer" :)

Comment: Homebrewers also make wine and mead.  (Whether the ones on the SE site do, I don't know.  But in general...)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - wine is not "brewed" .. though I suppose you could lump them together a bit :)

Comment: Right; brewing vs vintning.  But they have a bunch of questions about wine, so it looks like both are in scope there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer; you get a lot of the flavour from the yeast, you can get a fairly big difference by varying the yeast in your recipe.

For example, a Saison and a Pale ale have similar ingredients, but taste quite different, a Saison yeast imparts a considerable amount of flavour... likewise if you use a lager yeast, and properly lager your beer, you can get a different flavour again, without modifying any other part of your recipe.

Lots of discussion on HomeBrewTalk forums, and other places. For a fun experiment, brew split batches and try two different yeasts to compare!